# Save cart items into database

Tags: php, html

I have made a basic shopping website where a customer can add an item to their cart and then view their cart, they must be able to checkout and the items from the cart must be inserted into the database.

This is the code I have used to add my item to my `cart.php` using a session array as its multiple items that can be added to your cart.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("DBConn.php");
    $msg = "";

    if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        {
            $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");
            if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))
            {
                $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
                $item_array = array(
                    'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
                    'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_item"],
                    'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
                );
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="book_a_venue.php"</script>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $item_array = array(
                    'item_id'           =>  $_GET["id"],
                    'item_name'         =>  $_POST["hidden_item"],
                    'item_price'        =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'item_quantity'     =>  $_POST["quantity"]
            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the code I have used to retrieve the items from the session and display it, each item is displayed in a form that is created dynamically. This is the items that I'd like to insert into my database to save the order.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])){
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
?>
                                    
<form method="post" action="cart.php?action=remove&id="id" class="cart-items">
    <div class="border rounded">
        <div class="row bg-white">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></h4>
              <h4 class="text-danger">Price: R <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></h4>
              </br>
              <a href="cart.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="btn btn-danger mx2">Remove</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 py-5">
               <div>
               <h5>Quantity</h5>
               </br>
               <h4 name="quantity" class="text-info"><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></h4>
               <h3>R <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2);?></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
    $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);
    }
}
?>
```

This what I have tried to do in order to insert the items from the cart into the database. Which does not work and probably completely wrong.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])){
            $total = 0;
            
            
            
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
            {
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_order (`item`, `price`, `quantity`, `totalprice`, `total`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $item, $price, $quantity, $totalprice, $total);
            
            $item = $values["item_name"];
            $price = $values["item_price"];
            $quantity = $values["item_quantity"];
            $totalprice = $values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"];
            $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);
            $stmt->execute();
            }           
            $stmt->close();
            $con->close();          
        }   
?>

<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1 border rounded mt-5 bg-white h-25">
  <div class="pt-4">
    <h6>
        PRICE DETAILS
    </h6>
    <hr>
        <div class="row price-details">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>
                Delivery Charges
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <h6>
            Amount Payable
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <h6>
            Grand Total
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" class="btn btn-warning" id="btnHome" onClick="document.location.href='book_a_venue.php'"/>   
        </div>
                
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6 class="text-success">
                FREE
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <h6>
            R <?php echo number_format($total, 2);?>
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <h6>
            R <?php echo number_format($total, 2);?>
            </h6>
            <hr>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2">Check Out</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: It's not completely wrong, you're on the right path, the only problem that I can see is that you aren't concatenating the strings in your `INSERT` query. I'll leave this question to someone more experienced in PHP to provide a better answer (that probably isn't the only issue). +1 for using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` (many beginners I see tend to use `mysql`, which is obsolete and a security risk if not used properly).

Comment: @AStopher Thank you, that was actually a vote of confidence to me and being student, been stuck with issue for way to long and trying every way to get assistance on it.

Comment: @Dharman I am aware of the SQL Injections and currently working on that in the remake of this project

Comment: Can you show us the updated code? The one using parameter binding? Are you still experiencing issues with prepared statement?

Comment: @Dharman is right, this may be resolved if you change to parameterised prepared statements (they aren't difficult to master) because that'll also resolve the string concat issue. If you've done that and are still having issues, edit your question to add your updated code.

Comment: I haven't learnt about parameter binding before neither have been taught it at school so I am still learning the correct way to implement in my code on my new project.

Comment: I am using this to learn more about it https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: In terms of me getting the items from the session before my insert statement is that correct?

Comment: I have updated my code above

Comment: You are binding 5 variables but you have 3 `"sss"`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue, kind of a really stupid issue, I never had `<form method="post"></form>` on my checkout button, everything inserts correctly into the database now.
Thank you all who assisted me, it will really help me to improve my code.